# Diagonalizing a system of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

I need to solve this system of differential equations:

$\dot{A}=g_1AC+g_2A^2+g_3C^2$

$\dot{B}=g_1BC+g_2C^2+g_3B^2$

$\dot{C}=\frac{g_1}{2}(AB+C^2)+g_2AC+g_3BC$

Probably I can try to write it in the form of $\dot{X}=X^2$ where $X=aA+bB+cC$ but I'm not quite sure of how to proceed in this way.

Does Mathematica is able to solve that?
Or does anyone have any idea of how to handle the system above?

Thank you!

Comment: What is $g_1,g_2,g_3$? I think Mathematica can solve it.

Comment: Hi! they are parameters I need to have free in the final solution. Do you know how to work with $\dot{X}=X^2$ or can you give me some reference about?

Comment: $\dot{X}=X^2$ is easy to [solve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+dx%2Fdt%3Dx^2), but I don't know what has it to do with you system.

Comment: because if, for certain values of $a$,$b$ and $c$ (that will be equal to certain combinations of the $g$), I can transform the above system of differential equations in $\dot{X}=X^2$ which is easy to solve!